# Series about mutants and humans living and fighting around Richmond, VA

Tags: story-identification, mutant

As a teenager, I read a set of Scifi novels about mutants and humans that rode horses in and around Richmond, VA. I remember that they fought using swords and such. I also seem to remember some reference to a Sea of Grass.

Anyone remember the author/name of the series?

Comment: When were you a teenager? Can you estimate a publication date? Remember any specific characters/scenes, etc.?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/132644/series-of-novels-with-immortal-man-and-tribes-with-horses-telepathic-cats-in-p

Comment: You are correct Otis. Thanks.

Comment: duplicate confirmed by OP comment above

Answer (score 6):

I'll take a stab at the ***Horseclans*** novels by Robert Adams

[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horseclans)

> The books mainly concern the doings of the "Horseclans", a nomadic people originating from the **"Sea of Grass"** —the Great Plains from present-day southern Canada to central Texas, and from the Mississippi River to the Rocky Mountains, post-apocalyptically. The Horseclansmen were portrayed as fierce, noble and often gifted with telepathy, which came in handy for their dealings with their horses and "cats"—sabertoothed tigers that had been revived by scientific means in the years before the nuclear war.

Comment: THAT'S IT!!! Thanks so much @Paulie_D. Now, on to Amazon. .  .

Comment: You are very welcome Feel free to mark this answer as "accepted" by clicking the tick mark under the voting counts.